# Django: How do I update my inventory in the database of only the boxes that are checked?

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a web application that will serve as a grocery store. I want it to work in a way so that when customers click on the checkbox and click submit, then the database will subtract the inventory quantity by 1. I am having trouble being able to capture the information from the checkboxes and then using that to subtract 1 from the inventory.

models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=1)
    Sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
    class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'


    class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'Price', 'Sale', 'quantity', 'category',]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        Post = self.get_object()
        #editor = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == Post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

home.html

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.quantity > 0 %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" id=" {{ post.id }} ">
            <article class="media content-section">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ 
    post.category }}</a>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ 
    post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
                <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
                Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
              </input>
              </div>
            </article>
        {% else %}
          <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
              <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ 
    post.category }}</a>
              </div>
              <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ 
    post.title }}</a></h2>
              <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
              <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
              Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
              <p>Out Of Stock!</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" name="Purchase">Confirm Purchase</button>
    {% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
```

I have attached a picture of what the home page looks like as a reference. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: home.html]

Answer (score 2):

Include `{{ post.id }}` as value to checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="products" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.id }}" />
```

Then get the selected checkboxes in the view:

```
request.POST.getlist('products')
```

Here you will be getting the list of `id` of selected products and you can use it to decrease the quantity.